# Can't install hadoop on terminal

Tags: hadoop, homebrew

I am trying to install hadoop using $brew install hadoop but it shows the following:

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "hadoop".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I tried searching for it with $ brew search hadoop
But it says

```
Error: No formulae or casks found for "hadoop".
```

*My homebrew is already installed (in that I successfully type $brew help
How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `brew update` first.
If the problem persists, please share the output for `brew doctor`